# PostgreSQL COALESCE with IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, coalesce

I have the following example statement with PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT ((? IS NULL) OR (1 IN ?))
```

Where ? can either be `null` or something like `(1, 2, 3)`. It obviously works fine for non-null, but causes a syntax-error for null values.

I've been trying around with COALESCE but without any luck or Google help so far.

How can I write the above statement properly to handle `? = NULL` ?

Comment: You cannot represent lists like that in SQL.  In Postgres, you might consider using arrays instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Postgres `array` instead of a list, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(1 = any(null), true) a,
    coalesce(1 = any(array[1,2,3]), true) b,
    coalesce(1 = any('{1,2,3}'), true) c;

 a | b | c 
---+---+---
 t | t | t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Excellent answer that solves all my problems. Thank you!